# Как правильно декодировать JSON запрос?

Tags: golang

Делаю API с некоторым количеством методов. Запросы поступают с телом в формате JSON.

В найденных материалах предлагается декодировать запрос следующим образом:

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
var t test_struct   
err := decoder.Decode(&t)
```

Т.е. на КАЖДЫЙ метод API с различными параметрами запроса, мне нужно делать структуру?

Вопрос: насколько это хороший подход, если нет, то как лучше делать?

Answer (score 1):

> Т.е. на КАЖДЫЙ метод API с различными параметрами запроса, мне нужно делать структуру?

Почему вас это так смущает? Каждый запрос и каждый ответ являются по сути отдельными сущностями, так что вполне логично представить их в качестве типа.

Альтернативой является возня с `map[string]interface{}` и постоянные утверждения типов (type assertions), которые могут будут паниковать, если их неправильно написать. Оно вам надо?

Пишите типы и будет счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень полезный пакет  [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) для быстрого и простого получения значений из JSON. Очень помогает, к примеру если API непредсказуемое и сложно заранее подготовить структуры под все варианты ответов.

Мы просто на вход, подаем строчку JSON и указываем путь до нужного нам значения.

```
package main

import "github.com/tidwall/gjson"

const json = `{"name":{"first":"Janet","last":"Prichard"},"age":47}`

func main() {
    value := gjson.Get(json, "name.last")
    println(value.String())
}
```